# Possible to have multiple git users logged in as root?

Tags: linux, git

Is it possible to have multiple git users logged as the same Linux user?

What I would like is that multiple admins can login as `root`, make a `git pull` to a directory assigned to them, and then `git push`, but so we still can see who made which changes in the git log?

Comment: why are multiple users logging in as root - that is probably the more important question imo.

Comment: Why do all admins have to work as `root`? Why can't everyone login, pull and push as a regular user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each one of your users can `clone` the repo for his own. That repository would have his `config.user` and `config.email` according to the person using it, and they all `pull` and `push` to the same "central" repo.

Anyway, they are all `root`, so there's not much to do about preventing one of this admins to `commit` as another one. But if they aren't *evil*, you can do this.

[`gitosis`](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-7.html) can surely help to access control the repository, too, if needed.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would say that the correct mechanism to make sure that you can track changes in this sort of case would be not to have root as a permitted username for your repository.  They would all have to commit with their individual user names by logging in as themselves.

*In general nobody should be logged in as root other than very briefly while performing a specific task such as installing a new package - not all of the time while developing so anything you do to make such practices unrewarding is good.*

Answer (score 2):

It would be safer to manage that kind of access control with an [authorization layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/auth.html) like **[gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/)**, instead of relying on system account.

That way, you are controlling who can pull what.
Although that wouldn't control the "where" part (where the users would pull those repos to)